# Tile image animation on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: animation, windows-phone-8.1, tiles

I am trying to implement live tiles in my Windows phone 8.1 application. I saw nice feature in default Photos application. When on tile displaying large picture, it starting to "float" inside tile. Can anyone tell me how to achive this effect? I have read all info in the internet, but nowhere can find anything about that.

Here is what i am talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Silverlight app, you can get this exact behavior using [CycleTileTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207036%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to show upto 9 images.

If you're using XAML app, you can use [notification queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781199.aspx) (by calling `EnableNotificationQueue` in your `TileUpdater` object) to queue up to 5 tile updates, each containing an image, so that they'll be shown one after another. However, the tile updates do not slide as the Photos app. Instead they flip to show different queued updates.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I am using XAML app and using notification queue already. But i want to achieve exectly this effect like in `CycleTileTemplate` instead of flipping. Is there no way to achieve it in XAML Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: Currently there is no way to achieve that. You can also take a look at [TileWide310x150ImageCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx#TileWideImageCollection) template (similar to People hub) if that suits your need.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. But its not what i looking for.